# Socket.io acknowledgement do cliente para o servidor

Tags: socket.io

Sei que é possível usar funções de callback no socket.io, um exemplo é encontrado no link http://socket.io/docs

EXEMPLO

Cliente

```
socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Servidor

```
socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
    fn('woot');
});
```

Neste caso, a função de *callback* tem a seguinte direção: servidor para cliente

O que estou tentando sem sucesso é que a função de *callback* funcione do cliente para o servidor

Obrigado

Comment: Só achei um report que a confirmação do servidor para o cliente não funciona quando o evento não tem parâmetros: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1172